# Open source application that uses personal access token to access 3rd party API. How to use it in a safe way?

Tags: api, security, github, token

I have an open source application hosted in GitHub that uses a [Octokit.NET](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net) (a library to consume the GitHub AP).

In order to have more relaxed API rate limits, the API requires you to authenticate using a personal access token. I have that token, but I cannot use it in the code. I mean, my application makes use of the token, but since my releases are created automatically by Azure DevOps based on a specific commit, I'm out of luck.

**NOTE**: Making my users to use their own tokens is not an option.

How do I integrate the token in my app without compromising my security?

Answer (score 1):

The best things I can think of is either making a 'burner' account that is only used in the application or package the token in the code and compile it somehow.